# Reading JSON Files

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

been stuck on an issue trying to get the [coin ranking](https://docs.coinranking.com/) api to work but have gotten stuck.
I have been using fetch to log the JSON into the console but have not been able to figure out how to go inside a certain element.

```
fetch('https://api.coinranking.com/v1/public/coin/1')   
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

instead of all the data being logged i just want the data from 'data['coin']'

Comment: `.then(result => result.data.coin)` now you have a Promise that will resolve to what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing the response from the API you are consuming, "coin" is inside "data", so:

```
fetch('https://api.coinranking.com/v1/public/coin/1')   
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data.data.coin))
```

Comment: Thank you very much i didn't expect it to be such an obvious answer!

Comment: You may also consider using Axios instead of fetch(), which will omit the need for an extra step of .then(res => res.json())